# TableView Cells don't fit properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I added a table view programmatically in my code:

```
lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: UITableViewStyle.grouped)
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.delegate = self
    tv.dataSource = self
    return tv
}()
```

And then on viewDidLoad:

```
view.addSubview(tableView)
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

// Constraints
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.top, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottom, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.right, constant: 0).isActive = true
tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.left, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

But when my table view is displayed the cells don't fit properly from edge to edge, as shown in the following image:

[image: TableView image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help based on the screenshot, but try setting `tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` right before you add the tableView as a subview.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It actually was already in the code. It still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Did you make any changes to tableView's contentInset?

Comment: No I haven't. I'm still struggling with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to set:

```
tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
```